# Wordpress: Custom Post Types filter, sort and search

Tags: wordpress, filter, custom-post-type

I am using Custom Post types to display some information on a page.

[Wordpress Custom Post type displaying list of custom post type on existing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519888/wordpress-custom-post-type-displaying-list-of-custom-post-type-on-existing-page)

Is there a way to add filtering, Sorting and search functionality to the data?

I have manage to get Pagination to work "domain.com/page/2"

```
 $the_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'custom_post_type', 'posts_per_page' => 25, 'paged' => $paged, 'orderby'=>'title', 'order' => 'ASC'));
```

I was using jquery DataTable (http://datatables.net/) to add Sort, pagination and search but when you're using Datatable on 1000+ records it gets really sluggish and sometimes it displays php errors about out of memory.
This was always an interim solution until I figured out a way to do it properly with Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You are mentionning a jQuery tool to sort data, but this is not a good idea for data coming from a database. jQuery sort tools are made to make tables more readable and help the user play around with data already displayed on a page. With a database, the idea is moreso to only fetch the required data and not to get everything in the page and then sort or filter elements to get them out of the view (but still in the page, meaning it's heavier, longer to download, harder to process, etc.). 
You have managed to implement pagination for your custom post type, so that is fine. Now just include a search form. The default WordPress searchform (searchform.php) looks like this :

```
            <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
                <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
                    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

You just need to add a little line to it to restrict the search to your custom post types :

```
                    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="name_of_your_post_type" />
```

So it would go like this :

```
            <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
                <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
                    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="name_of_your_post_type" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks barakadam, I haven't tried the search yet but I was able to figure out order and orderby

I used $_GET to get the values for order and orderby and passed those variables in